# Чередование знаков у числа

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дан массив из N элементов. Нужно определить, чередуются ли знаки у чисел (больше нуля или меньше). Если чередуются, вывести 0, если нет, то вывести порядковый номер
Делаю это таким образом:

```
for(int i = 1; i < len; i++)
{
    if((mas[i-1] < 0 && mas[i] > 0) || (mas[i-1] > 0 && mas[i] < 0))
       cout<<0<<endl;
    else
        cout<<i+1<<endl;
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что приходится проверять с 1 элемента массива, то есть, 0 элемент не будет выводится
Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Порядковый номер чего надо вывести?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow элемента массива. Я вывожу i+1, ибо так для пользователя более понятно будет

Comment: Для пользователя будет понятно, когда выводится номер первого из пары, у которой знаки не чередуются

Comment: @VladfromMoscow это сейчас не так важно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Усовершенствованный вариант автора - пожалуй, наиболее лаконичный:

```
int i;
...
for(i = 1; i < len; i++)
    if(mas[i-1] * mas[i] > 0)
        break;
cout << (i == len ? 0 : i) << endl;
```

Или в виде функции:

```
int alternation(const int * mas, int len)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < len; i++)
        if(mas[i-1] * mas[i] > 0)
            break;
    return i == len ? 0 : i;
}
```

**UPD:**
Небольшое усовершенствование. В обоих случаях вместо выражения

```
i == len ? 0 : i
```

проще будет сделать так:

```
i % len
```

А если продолжать усовершенствования, то можно так:

```
int alternation(const int * mas, int len)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < len && mas[i-1] * mas[i] < 0; i++);
    return i % len;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Нашёл более простое решение:

```
cout<<0<<endl;

for(int i = 1; i < len; i++)
{
    if((mas[i-1] < 0 && mas[i] > 0) || (mas[i-1] > 0 && mas[i] < 0))
       cout<<0<<endl;
    else
        cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

По заданию, у меня в любом случае первым выведет 0, поэтому можно просто не обрабатывать нулевой элемент

Comment: просто нулевой элемент не может не чередоваться=), для этого нужно первым элементом выбрать `_m = -m[0]` и далее его и сравнивать с `m[i]` и обновлять `_m = m[i++]`

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то, 0 в качестве возвращаемого значения - неудачный выбор.

Задача легко решается с помощью стандартного алгоритма `std::adjacent_find`, объявленного в заголовке `<algorithm>`

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа. Если такая пара найдена, то выводится индекс первого элемента пары плюс 1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;

    int a[N] = { 0, -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6, -7, 8, -9 };
    int b[N] = { 0, -1, 2, -3, 4, 5, 6, -7, 8, -9 };

    auto it = std::adjacent_find( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ),
                                  [](  int x, int y )
                                  {
                                    return x >= 0 && y >= 0 || x < 0 && y < 0;  
                                  });

    if ( it == std::end( a ) )
    {
        std::cout << 0 << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << std::distance( std::begin( a ), it ) + 1 << std::endl;
    }

    it = std::adjacent_find( std::begin( b ), std::end( b ),
                             []( int x, int y )
                             {
                                return x >= 0 && y >= 0 || x < 0 && y < 0;  
                             });

    if ( it == std::end( b ) )
    {
        std::cout << 0 << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << std::distance( std::begin( b ), it ) + 1 << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
0
5
```

Comment: `x * y >= 0` попроще будет

Comment: @vp_arth В общем случае перемножение может привести к переполнению. А потому результат может быть неверный.

Answer (score 2):

И вот так :) Последний элемент при нечётном их количестве не учитываем. Значение `0` учитывается отдельно (два нуля подряд прокатят, чередование ноль/не ноль - нет).

```
#include <iostream>

static inline int sign( int a )
{
    return a == 0 ? 0 : a < 0 ? -1 : 1;
}

static bool alternation( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    int rc = 0;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < n - ( n % 2 ); i += 2 ) {
        rc += sign( a[i] ) + sign( a[i + 1] );
        if( rc ) {
            std::cout << "NO, i = " << i << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6 };
    int b[] = { -1, 1, 0, 0 };
    int c[] = { -1, 1, 2, 3 };

    alternation( a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) );
    alternation( b, sizeof(a)/sizeof(b[0]) );
    alternation( c, sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]) );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

std решение

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int m[] = { -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6, -7, 8 }, n = 8/*N*/, fe = n - 1, se = n - 2, e = n / 2 - 1;

    valarray<int> a(m, n);
    valarray<int> f = a[slice(0, fe, 2)];
    valarray<int> s = a[slice(1, se, 2)];
    sort (begin(f), begin(f)+e);
    sort (begin(s), begin(s)+e);

    if ((((*begin(f) > 0) && (*(begin(f) + e) > 0)) && ((*begin(s) < 0) && (*(begin(s) + e) < 0))) || (((*begin(f) < 0) && (*(begin(f) + e) < 0)) && ((*begin(s) > 0) && (*(begin(s) + e) > 0))))
        cout << "is the order of the conditions (0)" << endl;
    else
        cout << "no order sequence" << endl;    
}
```